# Can't import python module in .vimrc

Tags: vim, python, homebrew

So, I decided to try out powerline in vim, and for that reason I installed pypy using brew. I installed macvim as well and it is compiled with python support.

Following powerline installation instructions, I add the following lines to my `.vimrc`:

```
   python from powerline.vim import setup as powerline_setup
   python powerline_setup()
   python del powerline_setup
```

However, running vim then spits a couple of errors, first of which is:

```
ImportError: No module named powerline.vim
```

Now, I googled a bit and found out that setting PYTHONPATH env variable to

```
`brew -prefix`/lib/pypy/site-packages
```

would solve the issue, and indeed, there are no errors.

Since I have no python experience, what I am wondering is if this is the correct way to set $PYTHONPATH, and if so, why isn't this done by installation?

Also, if there are multiple python installations, is it OK for $PYTHONPATH to point to all of their site-packages?